# Reporting a rate off a comment field

Tags: reporting, formula

In our service org - all our custom flows write case comments for actions the agents take on the case.

For instance, when an agent reactivates a user, we write a comment that says, "Priceplan updated: xxxxx"

I need to get a rate of reactivations based on the text in the comments compared to the total number of cases.

Unsure if this is possible because formula fields only work with numbers... thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

have you checked out the process builder yet? It is a way of triggering actions based on clicks not code. You can make logical comparisons based on text and create actions based on the results. Also, formula fields are not just for numbers... you can do all sorts of evaluations, check out the docs here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=useful_advanced_formulas.htm&language=en_US

Hope this helps you on your journey!

Comment: Ahhhh - I meant the formula field in reporting.  :)  

But this process builder is genious - so I could check off a checkmark whenever the comment writes "free to paid" - and then report on the check mark against the total number of cases...

How would I create a formula that is looking for just part of the text in the comment field though?

Comment: Hi Stephanie, it is genius!! Totally moves us away from infinite trigger-code blockage! Yes you could report off a checkmark and the formula would be something like this:  CONTAINS(fieldtocheck , 'comparisonText')  = true. It might be broken out into segments in the process builder but that is the way you would use it on a formula field. Play with your process in a sandbox until you are happy with it :)